# gawk RS only at beginning of line with ^

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, gawk

Suppose I have multi line record with `=` as a record separator, but only if the `=` is the start of a line:

```
$ cat file
record 1, field 1
record 1, field 2 with a = in it
record 1, field 3
= record 2, field 1
record 2, field 2 also with a = in it
record 2, field 3
= final record 3, field 1
record 3, field 2
```

I would like to separate a file similar to this into records delimited by `^=[ \t]` and fields by `\n`.

I tried:

```
$ gawk -v RS="^=[ \t]" -v FS="\n" '{printf "%s\n--- NF=%s, NR=%s ---\n", $0, NF, FNR}' file
```

but that results in:

```
record 1, field 1
record 1, field 2 with a = in it
record 1, field 3
= record 2, field 1
record 2, field 2 also with a = in it
record 2, field 3
= final record 3, field 1
record 3, field 2

--- NF=9, NR=1 ---
```

i.e., the `^` does not work as I expect it to as beginning of the line.

I know I can do:

```
$ gawk -v RS="\n=[ \t]" -v FS="\n" '{printf "%s\nNF=%s, NR=%s\n", $0, NF, FNR}'
```

But that feels like it would have Unix / Windows issues with line separators. It also has an extra `\n` attached to the final record

I could use `sed` to replace the `^=[ \t]` with an extra `\n` then use `gawk` in paragraph mode:

```
$ sed 's/^=[ \t]/\
/' file | gawk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '{printf "%s\n--- NF=%s, NR=%s ---\n", $0, NF, FNR}'
record 1, field 1
record 1, field 2 with a = in it
record 1, field 3
--- NF=3, NR=1 ---
record 2, field 1
record 2, field 2 also with a = in it
record 2, field 3
--- NF=3, NR=2 ---
final record 3, field 1
record 3, field 2
--- NF=2, NR=3 ---
```

Which is *precisely* what I am looking for.

Question: Is there a way to use `^` in `RS` to indicate 'start of the line' in gawk with multiline records so I don't have to pipe through `sed`? I guess I am looking for the equivalent of the `m` flag in a PCRE regex in `gawk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` means `start of string`, not `start of line`. There is no `start of line` character, just carriage return (`\r` = return the cursor to the start of the line) and line feed (`\n` = drop the cursor to the next line) characters which together or separately depending on the tool/OS are used to indicate `end of line` aka `newline`. Windows tools tend to use `\r\n` to mean `newline` while UNIX uses `\n` alone which is is why `\n` is often referred to as the `newline character` in UNIX.

Many tools, e.g. `sed` and `grep` (and `awk` by default) only read 1 line at a time and so their input buffer contains a single line at a time and so in that context `start of string` is the same as `start of line` which is why you often hear `^` referred to as the `start of line` character when in general, it isn't. Similarly `$` is the `end of string` character, not the `end of line` character as it's often referred to but can be used to represent end of line when used in the context of a string input buffer that some tool is reading/populating one line at a time.

What that means is that if your tool is NOT reading one line at a time then the regexp to match a character `X` at the start of line in UNIX files is actually:

```
(^|\n)X
```

and at the end of a line is:

```
X(\n|$)
```

but be aware that that is also matching/consuming the linefeed char if present.

In Windows change `\n` to `\r\n` above and to work in both you can use `\r?\n` unless your file was created on Windows and could contain linefeed mid-line, e.g. CSVs exported from Excel could look like

```
field1,"field2 part a\nfield2 part b",field3\r\n
```

where the `\n` and `\r` would of course be literal. In that case you would not want the standalone `\n` mid-field to be misinterpreted as a newline.

Try this (gawk-only due to multi-char `RS` and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`):

```
$ awk -v RS='\n(=\\s*|$)' -F'\n' '{printf "%s\n--- NF=%s, NR=%s ---\n", $0, NF, FNR}' file
record 1, field 1
record 1, field 2 with a = in it
record 1, field 3
--- NF=3, NR=1 ---
record 2, field 1
record 2, field 2 also with a = in it
record 2, field 3
--- NF=3, NR=2 ---
final record 3, field 1
record 3, field 2
--- NF=2, NR=3 ---
```

Comment: Not a Windows guy, but does `\n` catch the `\r\n` on Windows?

Comment: @dawg I updated my answer with a discussion of what `\r\n` is vs `\n` alone and how to deal with both.

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid the last record extra new line by checking the last field

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS='\n=[ \t]' -v OFS='\n' '{NF-=$NF==""; 
                                            print $0, "---NF="NF ", ---NR="FNR}' file
record 1, field 1
record 1, field 2 with a = in it
record 1, field 3
---NF=3, ---NR=1
record 2, field 1
record 2, field 2 also with a = in it
record 2, field 3
---NF=3, ---NR=2
final record 3, field 1
record 3, field 2
---NF=2, ---NR=3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I found it slightly easier to do this inside of the BEGIN clause:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = "\n= "; FS = "\n"} {printf "%s\n--- NF=%s, NR=%s ---\n", $0, NF, FNR}' records
```

This gives the result:

```
record 1, field 1
record 1, field 2 with a = in it
record 1, field 3
--- NF=3, NR=1 ---
record 2, field 1
record 2, field 2 also with a = in it
record 2, field 3
--- NF=3, NR=2 ---
final record 3, field 1
record 3, field 2

--- NF=3, NR=3 ---
```

No explanation needed, as it really doesn't do anything but slightly reformulate what you already did.  How does that look?

The problem with ^, afaik, is that there are no "lines" per se.  There are records.  I could be wrong, but I don't think that the "start of line" concept is relevant in this context.  "Start of field" would be, or "start of record", although the latter would simply be something like:

```
$0 ~ /^chars/
```

But, I don't know much about the internal workings of this part of awk, so I welcome education on it.